# How should i feed this input into my regression network in tensorflow

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, regression

I am currently working with tensorflow, trying to implement a neural network for regression purposes. The regression consist of mapping a certain input to an output.   The input in my case samples and framed audio files, and the output it has to be mapped to is a set of MFCC features each frame should correspond to.

The input is currently stored like this.

```
#One audio set
[array([[frame],[frame],...,[frame]],dtype=float32)]
```

And the output is currently stored like this

```
[array([[Feature1,  Feature2,  Feature3,
         Feature4,  Feature5,  Feature6,
         Feature7,  Feature8,  Feature9,
         Feature10,   Feature11,   Feature12,
         Feature13],....,[...]])]
```

The model I am currently trying to input it to is a simple linear model. 
But since the input or the output data isn't a one dimensional dataset, I have to provide in a way such that it is capable of handling vector sizes.

```
# Set model weights
W = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="weight")
b = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="bias")


# Construct a linear model
pred = tf.add(tf.mul(X, W), b)
```

**Evaluated solutions**

One solution would be to flatten both the input, and output and make use of the fact that each frame and feature vector is consistent in length, and an make the weight `W` to matrix which has the size [frame_length, feature_length], and change the length of the bias to be the length of the feature_length.

Here is my attempt of doing this.

```
############################### Training setup ##################################
# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 1000
display_step = 50

# tf Graph Input
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None])

X_flatten = tf.reshape(X,[1,-1])
Y_flatten = tf.reshape(Y,[1,-1])

# Set model weights
W = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="weight")
W = tf.get_variable(name="W", shape=[train_set_data[0].shape[0],train_set_output[0].shape[0]])

b = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="bias")
b = tf.get_variable(name="b",shape=[1,train_set_output[0].shape[0]])

# Construct a linear model
pred = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, W), b)

# Mean squared error
cost = tf.nn.softmax(pred)

# Gradient descent
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    # Fit all training data
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        for (x, y) in zip(train_set_data, train_set_output):
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x, Y: y})

        #Display logs per epoch step
        if (epoch+1) % display_step == 0:
            c = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: train_set_data, Y:train_set_output})
            print "Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(c), \
                "W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b)

    print "Optimization Finished!"
    training_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: train_set_data, Y: train_set_output})
    print "Training cost=", training_cost, "W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b), '\n'

    #Graphic display
    plt.plot(train_set_data, train_set_output, 'ro', label='Original data')
    plt.plot(train_set_data, sess.run(W) * train_set_data + sess.run(b), label='Fitted line')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Problem here is I am getting an error message that I am not sure I understand..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow_datapreprocess_mfcc_extraction_rnn.py", line 177, in <module>
    pred = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, W), b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1036, in matmul
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 911, in _mat_mul
    transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 655, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2156, in create_op
    set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1612, in set_shapes_for_outputs
    shapes = shape_func(op)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/common_shapes.py", line 81, in matmul_shape
    a_shape = op.inputs[0].get_shape().with_rank(2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 625, in with_rank
    raise ValueError("Shape %s must have rank %d" % (self, rank))
ValueError: Shape (?,) must have rank 2
```

Could any explain why I am getting this error, or a different solution to the one i've provided. I am not that fond of the solution, as I am changing the initial input/output structure, rather than using the one created by prior preprocessing.